# Each new Excel worksheet linked to a different row of data

Tags: vba, excel

I have an Excel markbook that lists all of my pupils, and I have used a VBA to automatically name and hyperlink each cell in column A to a new worksheet which has a summary of each child, using a template sheet as the pattern for this.

```
Sub AutoAddSheet()

Dim MyCell As Range, MyRange As Range

Set MyRange = Sheets("DATA ENTRY").Range("A4")
Set MyRange = Range(MyRange, MyRange.End(xlDown))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

For Each MyCell In MyRange
Sheets("Template").Copy After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

 With Sheets(Sheets.Count)
   .Name = MyCell.Value
   .Cells(2, 1) = MyCell.Value

End With

MyCell.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=MyCell, Address:="", SubAddress:="'" & MyCell.Value & "'!A1"

Next MyCell
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I didn't know how to code to allow each new worksheet to also have a hyperlink back to the original data sheet, so just put that on the template sheet and it worked.

What I really want to do is be able to extract certain pieces of data from the DATA ENTRY sheet and have them on associated worksheets where the format does not change for each child - just the information. For example, child 1's name is in B4, but is in C2 on the worksheet for child 1, target grade is in E4 on DATA ENTRY, but in E5 on their personal sheet. Child 2's name is in B5 and target grade is E5, but C2 and E5 respectively for the worksheet for child 2. Child 3 = B6 and so on.

I have ten separate pieces of information from a very large original sheet that needs placing on separate worksheets associated with each child. Is there a way to do this, or do I manually have to go through and link the C2 cell in the child 1 worksheet back to B4 cell on the DATA ENTRY one? I have about 200 worksheets to go through so I'm hoping the former!

I have the following code now, but it only fills in the first sheet, rather than looping and filling in every other sheet for me:

```
Private Sub Setup_Sheets()
Dim Data_Entry As Worksheet          'You don't need variables. You can use Sheet1 and Sheet2 directly.
Set Data_Entry = Sheet1
Dim child1_sheet As Worksheet
Set child1_sheet = Sheet44            'Repeat for each child(sheet number is unqiue to your workbook)
Dim NameRange As Range
Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("B4")
child1_sheet.Range("C2").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("C4")
child1_sheet.Range("C3").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("D4")
child1_sheet.Range("C4").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("E4")
child1_sheet.Range("E5").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("G4")
child1_sheet.Range("G5").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("S4")
child1_sheet.Range("C9").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("AE4")
child1_sheet.Range("C10").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("AQ4")
child1_sheet.Range("C11").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("BC4")
child1_sheet.Range("C12").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("BE4")
child1_sheet.Range("F5").Value = NameRange.Value

End Sub
```

I also tried the following, but this fills every single sheet with the data of the first child. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
Private Sub Setup_with_loop()
Dim child_cnt As Integer
child_cnt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 2 To child_cnt                      'Assuming the first sheet is the data entry sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C2").Value = Sheet1.Range("B4").Value  
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C3").Value = Sheet1.Range("D4").Value  
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C4").Value = Sheet1.Range("F4").Value  
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("E5").Value = Sheet1.Range("G4").Value
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("G5").Value = Sheet1.Range("I4").Value 
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C9").Value = Sheet1.Range("U4").Value     
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C10").Value = Sheet1.Range("AG4").Value 
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C11").Value = Sheet1.Range("AS4").Value   
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C12").Value = Sheet1.Range("BE4").Value 
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("F5").Value = Sheet1.Range("BG4").Value   
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of manually linking, you could create some loops that go through your column with all the child's names, navigates to each sheet and places the data in the correct cells. Are the worksheets named after each child?

Comment: I want the sheet to become a template for every year, so just put numbers in column A, and linked those to each new worksheet, so they're all named numerically, rather than specifically by child (saves space in the tabs too!). I guess that if I could make a loop, then I wouldn't even need that, because I'd just rerun it every time I put new kids in. I will have to research loops though....a bit higher than my normal standard!

Answer (score 0):

you do not have to manually go through and link each cell. You can simply run a loop with the following code. Obviously you'll need to add a line for each of your pieces of data but the concept below should be enough to get you going. I do have to ask. Do you have 200 worksheets as in 200 children.  Or 200 workbooks with say 10 children each?

```
    Private Sub Setup_Sheets()
Dim Data_Entry As Worksheet          'You don't need variables. You can use Sheet1 and Sheet2 directly.
Set Data_Entry = Sheet1
Dim child1_sheet As Worksheet
Set child1_sheet = Sheet2            'Repeat for each child(sheet number is unqiue to your workbook)
Dim NameRange As Range
Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("B4")
child1_sheet.Range("C2").value = NameRange.value
End Sub
```

Or a cleaner but less descriptive method. Also showing the loop.

```
Private Sub Setup_with_loop()
Dim child_cnt As Integer
child_cnt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
For i = 2 To child_cnt                      'Assuming the first sheet is the data entry sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Range("C2").value = Sheet1.Range("B4").value  'Name
    'Add a line for each piece of data you need to copy
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have 200 sheets - one per child. I have tried the first code - it's working for the first sheet - it puts in the name of the child in their associated worksheet. However, nothing appears in any of the other sheets?

Comment: I did - but it only does the first sheet. I added the new code in a comment above. I tried to reply directly to you, but it wouldn't let me paste so much in the box?

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code now, but it only fills in the first sheet, rather than looping and filling in every other sheet for me:

```
Private Sub Setup_Sheets()
Dim Data_Entry As Worksheet          'You don't need variables. You can use Sheet1 and Sheet2 directly.
Set Data_Entry = Sheet1
Dim child1_sheet As Worksheet
Set child1_sheet = Sheet44            'Repeat for each child(sheet number is unqiue to your workbook)
Dim NameRange As Range
Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("B4")
child1_sheet.Range("C2").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("C4")
child1_sheet.Range("C3").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("D4")
child1_sheet.Range("C4").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("E4")
child1_sheet.Range("E5").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("G4")
child1_sheet.Range("G5").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("S4")
child1_sheet.Range("C9").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("AE4")
child1_sheet.Range("C10").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("AQ4")
child1_sheet.Range("C11").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("BC4")
child1_sheet.Range("C12").Value = NameRange.Value

Set NameRange = Data_Entry.Range("BE4")
child1_sheet.Range("F5").Value = NameRange.Value

End Sub
```